# How do I create actors that express hierarchical structures in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-cluster

I recently started developing using akka event sourcing/cluster sharding, and thanks to the online resources I think I understood the basic concepts and how to create a simple application with it. I am however struggling to apply this methodology in a slightly more complex data structure:

As an example, let's think about webpages and URLs.
Each Page can be represented with an actor in the cluster (having its unique id as the path of the page, e.g. /questions/60037683).

On each page I can issue commands such as

- Create page (so if the page does not exist, it will be created)
- Edit page (editing the details of the page)
- Get page content (and children)

Etc.

When issuing commands to single pages, everything is easy as it's "written on the manual". But I have the added the complexity that a web page can have children, so when creating a "child page" I need the parent to update references to its children.

I thought of some possible approaches, but they feel incomplete.

- Sending all events to the single WebPage and when creating a page, finding the parent page (if any) and communicate that a new child has been added
- Sending all events to the single WebPage, and when creating a page, the message is sent to the parent, and then it will create a new command that will tell the child to initialize
- Creating an infrastructure as WebPageRepository that will keep track of the page tree and will relay CRUD commands to all web page actors.

My real problem is, I think, handling the return of Futures properly when relaying messages to other actors that have to actually perform the job.

I'm making a lot of confusion and some reading resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: the first version was talking about a generical hierarchical file-system-like structure. I updated with the real purpose, webpages and urls and tried to clarify better my issues

Comment: First of all... this example of directories and files is kind of awkward, as directories and files are static resources and are not really a great use case for actors. Second thing is that every system design is a highly opinion and requirement based problem. So, even if you provide a better example, I am not sure that our suggestions will be of any benefit for your purpose.

Comment: Well, "this is not really a great use case for actors" is a totally acceptable answer, and I was already starting to think about that. The example, though, still fits as the real use case is not files and directories, but web pages, so yes basically still static stuff as you pointed out. I will still wait for other people's opinions while at the same time go back to the design table to think about it in another, maybe more classical, way. Thank you.

Comment: The moment you start to talk about web pages / urls... things change a lot. Because, if your actors are more like "clients for atomically accessing those urls", then actor model suddenly starts to make a lot more sense.

Comment: Yes, that was what I intended: an actor == webpage is univocally identified in the cluster by its path (e.g. /questions/60037683) and I can perform operations on that webpage, e.g. editing it or publishing a sub-page within itself. That's when the trouble starts, when nesting pages into other pages, and having the entire system know that this nested structure has changed.

Comment: @Luca Why do you need to "*hav[e] the entire system know that this nested structure has changed*"? Wouldn't a listener be interested in only a specific directory changing?

Comment: In my example, when I create a page as a direct child of another page, I need to notify the parent that their children have changed. I don't necessary need the entire system know that, I expressed myself wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some months of searching, I reached the conclusion that what I'm doing is trying to have actors behave transactionally, so that when something is created, the parent is also updated in a safe manner, meaning that if one operation fails, all operations who completed successfully are rolled back.
The best pattern for this, in my opinion, proved to be the saga pattern, which adds a bit of complexity to the whole process, but in the long run it does what I needed.

Basically I ended up implementing the main actor as a stand alone piece (as it should be) that can receive create commands and add children commands.

There is then a saga actor which takes care of creating the content, adding the child to the parent and rolling back everything if something fails during the process.

If someone else has a better solution, I'll be glad to hear it out